# Determine when one multi-variable function exceeds another

Tags: algorithms

Given the following two functions, how can I determine an equation for when the first is greater than the second?

$$n\log(k)$$ and
$$n + k\log(n)$$

I graphed them, and found a distinct intersection line of the planes, but mathematica was unable to solve the intersection.

My intuition says to take partial derivatives of both, but I am unsure how to use the information from those derivatives to find the equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly you have $k$ and $n$ both positive to have real logarithms

I suspect you can separate the variables to get 
$$\frac{\log(k) -1}{k} =  \frac{\log(n)}{n}$$

A solution for this will involve the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) or something similarly complicated and I think will give $$n = e^{-W\left(-\frac{\log(k)-1}{k}\right)}$$

Note that the Lambert W function is multivalued and that for $k \gt e$ there will be two values of $n$ satisfying the equality

So for example with $k=10$, you get   $n\log(k) \gt n + k\log(n)$ when either $0 \lt n \lt 1.16366878\ldots$ or $n \gt 24.5819976\ldots$

Comment: What allowed the removal of log(n) from given Lambert function?

Comment: @awsunit If a solution to $xe^x=c$ is $x=W(c)$ then a solution to $\frac{\log(x)}{x}=c$ is $x=e^{-W(-c)}$